# Remove button Find and Clear in GridControl

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

like I can eliminate the botton (Find and Clean) of a GridControl, and alone to leave TextEdit.

[image]
regards
Alex

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Can I ask why you'd like to? BTW, you can always just add a textbox and add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach demonstrated in [How to customize the Find Panel layout?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2806.aspx) example:

1. Create the GridControl/GridView descendant components
2. Override the `GridView.CreateFindPanel` method to provide your
   own customized `FindControl` instance into the view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you will need to access the FindControl and then access the layoutControl and its Control Items. Use the Code below in form_load etc:

```
         // Get the Find Control on Grid : gcMain
        FindControl _FindControl = gcMain.Controls.Find("FindControl", true)[0] as FindControl;

           //Get the Layout Control
        LayoutControl lc = (_FindControl.ClearButton.Parent as LayoutControl);

        //Allow Control Hiding 
        lc.Root.AllowHide = true;

        //Hide Find Button
        (lc.Root.Items[2] as LayoutControlItem).ContentVisible = false;


        //Hide Clear Button
        (lc.Root.Items[3] as LayoutControlItem).ContentVisible = false;
```